# Shutdown-Script for Don't Starve Together Dedicated Server

Tags: game, lua

I have written my first LUA-Script/Function to shut down the Dedicated Server for Don't Starve Together.
I wanted to shut down the server in 2 minutes and inform everyone on the server that the server is shutting down.
The function `os.execute` is `nil` in the dedicated server console, so I can't use `os.execute("sleep " .. seconds)`.

Can I improve something on this script? Is it best practice?

```lua
function sleep(seconds)
    local t = os.time()
    local diff = 0
    while diff < seconds do
        diff = os.difftime(os.time(), t)
    end
end

local steps = {120,60,30,10,5,4,3,2,1}
local n = table.getn(steps)
for i=1,n-1,1 do
  TheNet:SystemMessage("The server shuts down in " .. steps[i] .. " seconds")
  sleep(steps[i] - steps[i+1])
end
TheNet:SystemMessage("The server shuts down in " .. steps[n] .. " seconds")
sleep(steps[n])
TheNet:SystemMessage("The server is shutting down now")
c_shutdown(true)
```

[Link](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Console/Don%27t_Starve_Together_Commands) to the server command list for Don't Starve.

- `TheNet:SystemMessage` prints the message into the chat
- `c_shutdown(true)` shutdown the server and persist the world

Comment: I think is correct. Some nit suggestions are: 1) in the for loop, by default increase is '+1' so it's not necessary to type it ('for i=1,n-1 do' works too) 2) instead of 'table.getn(steps)' could simply write '#steps'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`table.getn` has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31452871/1190388) for more than 2 years now.
2. Why iterate only until `n-1`?
3. I'd prefer using the [`string.format`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-string.format) over plain concatenation. This is just a personal preference, as the strings are easier to read that way.
4. Although you do not need to pass `true` to the `c_shutdown`, do mention in a comment what it does. Maintaining comments is a nice way to recognise engine specific hard-bound parameters; without having to refer the docs again.
5. Iterate over the table using [`ipairs`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-ipairs)

Rewritten, the code would be:

```
local function sleep(seconds)
    local diff, t = 0, os.time()
    while diff < seconds do
        diff = os.difftime(os.time(), t)
    end
end

local steps = {
  120, 60, 30,
  10, 5, 4, 3,
  2, 1
}
local notice = "The server shuts down in %d seconds"

for _, secs in ipairs(steps) do
  TheNet:SystemMessage(notice:format(secs))
  sleep(secs)
end
TheNet:SystemMessage("The server is shutting down now")
c_shutdown(true)  -- true parameter implies that the game will be saved
```

Comment: 1. ok
2. only until n-1, because: steps[i+1]
3. cool thing
4. ok
5. this ipairs strategy is not so clear for me. the _ stands for the key and this isn't used. Isn't there anything like foreach?

Comment: @Shinigami `ipairs` is the same as `foreach`. I am not using `_` because we are not interested in the index of each value. If you want, you can replace `secs` with `steps[_]`. `foreach` loops, AFAIK, also iterate over `key => value` pairs, and both values are returned in the generators.

Answer (score 1):

```lua
function sleep(seconds)
    local t = os.time()
    local diff = 0
    while diff < seconds do
        diff = os.difftime(os.time(), t)
    end
end
```

Correct me, but as far as I can see, that's a busy sleep, which might also be called "let's see how fast the CPU can go" sleep.

You need a "native" sleep function, something that is being woken up by the OS as to not make the CPU spin, or any other sort of callback after a certain amount of time.

---

```lua
local t = os.time()
```

Do not shorten variable names just because you can, it makes the code harder to read and harder to maintain.

---

```lua
local steps = {120,60,30,10,5,4,3,2,1}
```

You could also sleep for half the amount of time, like this:

````lua
local timeUntilShutdownInSeconds = 120;

while timeUntilShutdownInSeconds >= 1 do
    -- Do Something
    timeUntilShutdownInSeconds = timeUntilShutdownInSeconds / 2
    sleep(timeUntilShutdownInSeconds)
end
```
````